# Ring with unit and such that $a+^1 b = a+b+1, a\cdot^1 b = a\cdot b+a+b$, prove its ring and find identity and inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We have in the ring $A$ with unit $1$ and then using the usual $+$ and $\cdot$ from $A$ we create new operations

$$a+^1b = a+b+1\\ a\cdot^1 b = ab+a+b$$

In order to prove its a ring I must prove first that this is a group

The identity of the sum is $(-1)$ because:

$$a+^1(-1) = a+(-1)+(1) = a$$

And the inverse element of the sum I think is $(-a-2)$:

$$a+(-a-2) = a+-a-2 + 1 = -1$$

Also, we must have associativity in the sum:

$$a+^1(b+^1c) = a+^1(b+c+1) = a+(b+c+1)+1 = (a+b+1)+c+1 = (a+^1b)+c+1 = (a+^1c)+^1 c$$
(see that I had to use commutativity of the sum :(

Also, for rings, we must have associativity and distributivity:

$$(a\cdot^1 b)\cdot^1 c = (ab+a+b)\cdot^1c = (ab+a+b)c + (ab+a+b) + c = abc + ac + bc + ab+a+b+c$$
$$a\cdot^1(b\cdot^1c) = a\cdot^1(bc+b+c) = a(bc+b+c) + a + (bc+b+c) = abc + ab + ac + a + bc+b+c$$

so the two are equal.

$$a\cdot^1(b+c) = a(b+c)+a+(b+c) = ab+ac+a+b+c = ab+a+c + ac + c = a\cdot^1b + ac+\color{red}{a} +c = a\cdot^1b + a\cdot^1c$$

the $\color{red}{a}$ is missing but I might have typed something wrong.

$$(a+b)\cdot^1c = (a+b)c + (a+b) + c = ac + bc + a + b + c = ac + a + c + bc + b  + \color{red}{c} = a\cdot^1c + b\cdot^1 c$$

well, another letter is missing. Am I doing something wrong?

What did you guys think of my proof?

Comment: Note that the commutativity of $+'$ follows from the commutativity of $+$.